# how to move object based on other object (e.g. plane) axis using rigidbody - Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I am looking for any idea how to move GameObject based on other object's axis. It's hard to translate it for me, so I use a "real" examples:

1. I have a table and want to move plate on it. It's of course, I can move it only in two directions.
2. I have a floor and want to move a ball on it. Repeat, I have only two directions to do that.

I know how to move my object in my mouse direction, but it's always X, Y and Z axis. I'm using Rigidbody.AddForce so I need to use global/world coordinates. So I can't "just don't use" one direction, because my first object (table, floor etc.) can move, rotate etc. So I think I should move my object (plate, ball) basing on local coordinates of first object. But I completely haven't idea how to find direction/vector? I know it's math possible, but I feel mess.

It's REALLY IMPORTANT to do that by rigidbody - NOT translate (by translate it's quite easy for me ;)).

I hope my post is understable, because it's hard to translate this problem for me. If I should precise something - please, write.

---

EDIT: This post was marked as a duplicate, but I don't see answer on my question on the second post. I want to move my objects relative to other surface using rigidbody, proposed post don't tell about it.

Comment: You move Rigidbody with `Rigidbody.MovePosition`. I am sure sure you could have found this if you Googled how to move a rigidbody...

Comment: I've eddited my post with information that it's not a problem HOW TO MOVE. It's a problem HOW TO MOVE BASED ON OTHER OBJECT COORDINATES.

Comment: The duplicate shows you how to move a Rigidbody to another position. Use that to move your Rigidbody to another position. If it doesn't work, post your code. Without your code, no one knows what you are doing wrong

Comment: @Programmer I feel my problem is enough understable for you or something in my thinking is wrong. So I'll try to explain it repeat. I have first object, e.g. wall. It has local coordinates and world coordinates, of course. It's not moving, but I don't know it's coordinates (so it can be rotated etc.). Now I have an object that has rigidbody and I want to move it "like a picture on a wall" (or something like that). It means that my second object is moving ON FLAT SURFACE of first object. I'm doing it by mouse position and adding force to mouse position. But this way I have position in 3.

Comment: dimensions - XYZ. So it's not "sticked" to wall. But I want to move it ONLY on wall surface. I'm really trying to translate it as exactly as possible, but my english isn't enough good to do it with better language.